# Rails prawn chart not rendered completely at the bottom of the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I am creating a pdf report in order to show some data using the "squid" gem. This would allow me to display charts in my pdf.
The only issue i found is that when the chart does not fit at the bottom of the page then it looks rendered partially which does not look good at all. Any idea how can i fix this?

[image]

Here is the code i am using to render the charts

```
require 'squid'

class SurveyPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(survey, view)
    super()
    font "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts/roboto-condensed.ttf"

    @survey = survey
    @view = view
    questions
  end

  def questions
    @survey.questions.each do |question|
      text "#{question.title}", size: 20
      text "Answers #{question.answers.size}", size: 15
      if ["single", "select"].include? question.question_type.prefix
        if question.answers.choice_counter.any?
          chart choices: question.answers.choice_counter
        end
      end
      if question.question_type.prefix == "image"
        if question.answers.image_counter.any?
          chart images: question.answers.image_counter
        end
      end
      if question.question_type.prefix == "multiple"
        if question.answers.multiple_choice_counter.any?
          chart choices: question.answers.multiple_choice_counter
        end
      end
      if question.question_type.prefix == "raiting"
        move_down 5
        if question.answers.any?
          text_box "Average rating", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [0,  cursor - 2]
          text_box "#{average_rating(question.answers.rating_average)}", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [4 * 30,  cursor - 2]
        else
          text_box "Average rating", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [0,  cursor - 2]
          text_box "0", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [4 * 30,  cursor - 2]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the solution I would use it to determine if the chart can fit in the remaining space and if not then add a page and render there. e.g. current cursor position + chart height > bottom of page

Comment: What is bottom of page? Can you show me with some code if possible?

Comment: I have added an "Answer" more to answer your comment than you question but it should help with both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in your comment as to determining page size I will run through a few useful methods too long for a comment:

```
d = Prawn::Document.new
d.y #full page height
d.margin_box.bottom #actually top since prawn starts at the bottom
d.margin_box.absolute_bottom #actual top with margins included
d.margin_box.top #usable page height
d.margin_box.absolute_top #same as #y 
d.cursor #where you are vertically on the page
```

So you can use some basic math to determine fit:

```
#this is all chart does excepting chart calls #draw 
#which we don't want to do until we determine if it fits 
c = Squid::Graph.new(d, choices: question.answers.choice_counter) 

#determine if the chart will fit vertically 
#if not start a new page and move to the top
unless d.cursor + c.height < d.margin_box.top
   d.start_new_page
   d.move_cursor_to(0)
end

#draw the chart onto the appropriate page
c.draw
```

Hope this helps in some way

Comment: Well i fix it using something similar if (842 - cursor) + 250 > 842 start_new_page otherwise stay_in_same_page

Comment: @adavia glad you got it working. Sorry it took a bit to get back to you I have never used `squid` before and had to do a little source review to determine how `chart` was implemented before I could pose a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1):

**For a similar issue I used the [prawn-grouping gem](https://github.com/ddengler/prawn-grouping)**

It pre-renders whatever you place in a `group` block to test whether it fits on the current page. If not, it skips to the next page and renders.

In your case you would do something like:

```
def questions
  @survey.questions.each do |question|
    group :too_tall => lambda { start_new_page } do |g|
      g.text "#{question.title}", size: 20
      g.text "Answers #{question.answers.size}", size: 15
      if ["single", "select"].include? question.question_type.prefix
        if question.answers.choice_counter.any?
          g.chart choices: question.answers.choice_counter
        end
      end
      if question.question_type.prefix == "image"
        if question.answers.image_counter.any?
          g.chart images: question.answers.image_counter
        end
      end
      if question.question_type.prefix == "multiple"
        if question.answers.multiple_choice_counter.any?
          g.chart choices: question.answers.multiple_choice_counter
        end
      end
      if question.question_type.prefix == "raiting"
        move_down 5
        if question.answers.any?
          g.text_box "Average rating", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [0,  cursor - 2]
          g.text_box "#{average_rating(question.answers.rating_average)}", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [4 * 30,  cursor - 2]
        else
          g.text_box "Average rating", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [0,  cursor - 2]
          g.text_box "0", size: 12, width: 120, :at => [4 * 30,  cursor - 2]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*disclaimer:* I've never used **squid**  so the only piece I'm not sure of is `g.chart` let me know if you have issues there and I will try to figure it out.

**Update for squid**

The `prawn-grouping` gem doesn't know about the `squid` methods (like `chart`). So we can extract the logic from the `prawn-grouping` gem and add it directly in your `survey_pdf.rb`. Copy lines 7-63 from [this file](https://github.com/ddengler/prawn-grouping/blob/master/lib/prawn/grouping.rb), and remove `prawn-grouping` gem from your app.

*if you are curious why this works...*

`Squid` uses the `Prawn::Document.extensions` method to force `Prawn::Document` to inherit the squid methods. You can see that in the squid gem code [here on line 37](https://github.com/Fullscreen/squid/blob/master/lib/squid.rb#L37).

For `prawn-grouping` to work it creates a new `Prawn::Document` as part of the `group` method. You can see that [here on line 55](https://github.com/ddengler/prawn-grouping/blob/master/lib/prawn/grouping.rb#L55). The problem was that the `Prawn::Document` instantiated via the `prawn-grouping` gem wasn't inheriting the `squid` methods... but your `SurveyPdf` instance of `Prawn::Document` does inherit the `squid` methods, so by adding the `grouping` logic into your `SurveyPdf` class, now the `Prawn::Document` instantiated in your `group` method will work.

Comment: Yes i get undefined method `chart' for #<Prawn::Document:0xb006b084> when using g.chart

Comment: OK, I think I have that figured out. You're going to want to copy from line 7 to line 63 from [this file in the grouping gem](https://github.com/ddengler/prawn-grouping/blob/master/lib/prawn/grouping.rb) into your `survey_pdf.rb`. Then remove the grouping-gem from your app and re-run. If this works (pretty sure it will); I'll explain and update my answer

Comment: So i tried what you said, but i am not seeing any difference with this code. The chart should be jumping to the next page and is not.

Comment: rather than `group do |g|` do this: `group :too_tall => lambda { start_new_page } do |g|`. This will force it to start a new page per [this example](https://github.com/ddengler/prawn-grouping#options)

Comment: Same thing.. perhaps moving the chart into a span block or something similar?

Comment: Yes, maybe a span. In my similar use case my content is in a Prawn Table and works great. Is it still doubling up the content, too?

Comment: @BigRon how I use it with a table in a "group" context? I try something like this: ```closing_table = make_table([....``` and then ```group.closing_table.draw ``` but this is not working